# JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('priceSlider')).start , Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, rangeslider, jsonparser, reactivesearch

I am using Localstorage.getItem tocreate a RangeSlider with dynamic defaultSelected Values. I am using the rangeSlider inside a react-modal so I need when the user open the model and use the range slider to create a filter, the state is saved in LocalStorage and when the user open the modal again he get the rangeSlider with the last values he selected in the start and end Here is my code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onPriceValueChange = this.onPriceValueChange.bind(this);   
    localStorage.setItem('priceSlider','');
  }

 onPriceValueChange(value){
    console.log("value:",value)
    console.log("value.start:",value.start)
    localStorage.setItem('priceSlider', JSON.stringify(value));  
    console.log("localStorageonPrice:",localStorage)   
    var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('priceSlider'));
    console.log("OBJ:",obj);
    console.log("start:",JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('priceSlider')).start);
    console.log("end:",JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('priceSlider')).end);
  }
<Modal
       isOpen={this.props.PriceModalIsOpen}
       onHide={this.handleHide}
       contentLabel="Prix Modal"
 >
 <RangeSlider
    title="40000-80000"
    componentId="priceSlider"
    className="priceRangeSlider"
    dataField="price.keyword"
    range={{
     start: 0,
     end: 100000
    }}
    defaultSelected={{
     start: 20000,
     end: 50000
    }}
    rangeLabels={{
     start: "40",
     end: "80"
   }}                                      
    URLParams={false}
    onValueChange={this.onPriceValueChange}
    />
</Modal>
```

When I test with a static value for the defaultSelected like this

```
defaultSelected={{
                start: 20000,
                end: 50000
              }}
```

[image]

The console.log() shows:

[image]

but when I want to have the values chosen by the user when he closed the Modal
I tied with this:

```
defaultSelected={{
     start: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('priceSlider')).start,
     end: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('priceSlider')).end
    }}
```

But I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>   at JSON.parse ()
>   at ProxyComponent.render (PriceFilterModal.js:91)
>   at ProxyComponent.hotComponentRender (react-hot-loader.development.js:620)
>   at ProxyComponent.proxiedRender (react-hot-loader.development.js:635)
>   at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:13194)
>   at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:13156)
>   at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:13825)
>   at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:15864)
>   at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:15903)
>   at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:100)
>   at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:138)
>   at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:187)
>   at replayUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:15311)
>   at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:15963)
>   at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:16561)
>   at performWork (react-dom.development.js:16483)
>   at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:16455)
>   at requestWork (react-dom.development.js:16355)
>   at scheduleWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:16219)
>   at scheduleRootUpdate (react-dom.development.js:16786)
>   at updateContainerAtExpirationTime (react-dom.development.js:16813)
>   at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:16840)
>   at ReactRoot../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js.ReactRoot.render (react-dom.development.js:17123)
>   at react-dom.development.js:17263
>   at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:16680)
>   at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:17259)
>   at render (react-dom.development.js:17318)
>   at renderApp (index.js:11)
>   at Object. (index.js:19)
>   at Object../src/index.js (index.js:10)
>   at **webpack_require** (bootstrap c230f6f2604486566c3b:678)
>   at fn (bootstrap c230f6f2604486566c3b:88)
>   at Object.0 (index.less?83e0:26)
>   at **webpack_require** (bootstrap c230f6f2604486566c3b:678)
>   at bootstrap c230f6f2604486566c3b:724
>   at bootstrap c230f6f2604486566c3b:724
>
> render @ PriceFilterModal.js:91
>   hotComponentRender @ react-hot-loader.development.js:620
>   proxiedRender @ react-hot-loader.development.js:635
>   finishClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:13194
>   updateClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:13156
>   beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:13825
>   performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:15864
>       workLoop @ react-dom.development.js:15903
>       callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:100
>       invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:138
>       invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:187
>       replayUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:15311
>       renderRoot @ react-dom.development.js:15963
>       performWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:16561
>       performWork @ react-dom.development.js:16483
>       performSyncWork @ react-dom.development.js:16455
>       requestWork @ react-dom.development.js:16355
>       scheduleWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:16219
>       scheduleRootUpdate @ react-dom.development.js:16786
>       updateContainerAtExpirationTime @ react-dom.development.js:16813
>       updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:16840
>       ./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js.ReactRoot.render @ react-dom.development.js:17123
>       (anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:17263
>       unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:16680
>       legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:17259
>       render @ react-dom.development.js:17318
>       renderApp @ index.js:11
>       (anonymous) @ index.js:19
>       ./src/index.js @ index.js:10
>       **webpack_require** @ bootstrap c230f6f2604486566c3b:678
>       fn @ bootstrap c230f6f2604486566c3b:88
>       0 @ index.less?83e0:26
>       **webpack_require** @ bootstrap c230f6f2604486566c3b:678
>       (anonymous) @ bootstrap c230f6f2604486566c3b:724
>       (anonymous) @ bootstrap c230f6f2604486566c3b:724
>       index.js:2178 The above error occurred in the  component:
>           in PriceFilterModal (created by Connect(PriceFilterModal))
>           in Connect(PriceFilterModal) (at DefaultPage.js:36)
>           in div (at DefaultPage.js:31)
>           in DefaultPage (created by Connect(DefaultPage))
>           in Connect(DefaultPage) (created by Route)
>           in Route (at Root.js:32)
>           in Switch (at Root.js:41)
>           in div (at App.js:33)
>           in div (created by Styled(div))
>           in Styled(div) (created by URLParamsProvider)
>           in URLParamsProvider (created by Connect(URLParamsProvider))
>           in Connect(URLParamsProvider) (created by ReactiveBase)
>           in Provider (created by ReactiveBase)
>           in ThemeProvider (created by ReactiveBase)
>           in ReactiveBase (at App.js:29)
>           in div (at App.js:27)
>           in App (at Root.js:27)
>           in Route (at Root.js:25)
>           in Switch (created by Root)
>           in Router (created by ConnectedRouter)
>           in ConnectedRouter (created by Root)
>           in Provider (at Root.js:52)
>           in Root
>           in AppContainer (at index.js:12)

```
React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, ReactiveBase.
__stack_frame_overlay_proxy_console__ @ index.js:2178
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:14227
logError @ react-dom.development.js:14266
callback @ react-dom.development.js:14948
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:10879
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:10923
commitLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:14378
commitAllLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:15463
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:100
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:138
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:187
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:15604
completeRoot @ react-dom.development.js:16619
performWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:16564
performWork @ react-dom.development.js:16483
performSyncWork @ react-dom.development.js:16455
requestWork @ react-dom.development.js:16355
scheduleWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:16219
scheduleRootUpdate @ react-dom.development.js:16786
updateContainerAtExpirationTime @ react-dom.development.js:16813
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:16840
./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js.ReactRoot.render @ react-dom.development.js:17123
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:17263
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:16680
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:17259
render @ react-dom.development.js:17318
renderApp @ index.js:11
(anonymous) @ index.js:19
./src/index.js @ index.js:10
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap c230f6f2604486566c3b:678
fn @ bootstrap c230f6f2604486566c3b:88
0 @ index.less?83e0:26
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap c230f6f2604486566c3b:678
(anonymous) @ bootstrap c230f6f2604486566c3b:724
(anonymous) @ bootstrap c230f6f2604486566c3b:724
index.js:2178 An error has occured. You're using Reactivesearch Version: 2.8.1. If you think this is a problem with Reactivesearch, please try updating to the latest version. If you're already at the latest version, please open an issue at https://github.com/appbaseio/reactivesearch/issues
```

With Firefox I get:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

[image]

Comment: this error occurs when the value retrieved is in "[Object Object]"

Comment: Yes I got that [Object Object] that I way I am using JSON.parse and JSON.Stringify

Comment: so when you try to JSON.parse("[object object]"), it gives you this error.

Comment: Could you create a codesandbox demo? I can take a look.

Answer (score 1):

The below code would work. While storing into localstorage you need to store it with `JSON.stringify` and while getting the item you need to do `JSON.parse`

```
import React from "react"; 
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"; 
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'; 
import { connect } from 'react-redux'; 
import * as actions from './redux/actions'; 
import { closePriceModal } from '../filter-bar/redux/actions'; 
import Modal from 'react-modal'; 
import { RangeSlider } from '@appbaseio/reactivesearch'; 

export class PriceFilterModal extends Component { 
static propTypes = { 
  simpleFilter: PropTypes.object.isRequired, 
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired, 
  PriceModalIsOpen: PropTypes.bool.isRequired 
}; 

constructor(props) { 
  super(props); 
  localStorage.setItem('priceSlider', ''); 
} 

onPriceValueChange = value => { 
  localStorage.setItem("priceSlider", JSON.stringify(value));
  this.forceUpdate();
} 
handleHide = () => { 
  this.props.actions.closePriceModal(); 
} 

render() { 
  const priceSlider = localStorage.getItem("priceSlider");
  const start = JSON.parse(priceSlider).start;
  const end = JSON.parse(priceSlider).end;
  return ( 
    <div className="simple-filter-price-filter-modal"> 
      <Modal 
      isOpen={this.props.PriceModalIsOpen} 
      onHide={this.handleHide} 
      contentLabel="Prix Modal" 
      > 
          <div className="multiList"> 
            <RangeSlider
                title="40000-80000"
                componentId="priceSlider"
                className="priceRangeSlider"
                dataField="price.keyword"
                range={{
                  start: 0,
                  end: 100000
                }}
                defaultSelected={{
                  start: start,
                  end: end
                }}
                rangeLabels={{
                  start: "40000",
                  end: "80000"
                }}
                URLParams={false}
                onValueChange={this.onPriceValueChange}
              />
          </div> 
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleHide} className="btn btn-circle"></button> 
      </Modal> 
    </div > 
  ); 
} 
} 
function mapStateToProps(state) { 
  return { 
    simpleFilter: state.simpleFilter, 
  }; 
} 

/* istanbul ignore next */ 
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) { 
  return { 
    actions: bindActionCreators({ ...actions, closePriceModal }, dispatch) 
  }; 
} 

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PriceFilterModal);
```

Please find working demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/0ylx370kzp)

Comment: But I did it here  onPriceValueChange(value){
    
    localStorage.setItem('priceSlider', JSON.stringify(value));

Comment: I tried it now but I am getting: index.js:2178 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `defaultSelected.start` is marked as required in `RangeSlider`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in RangeSlider (created by Connect(RangeSlider)) . Also the slider is not activatedanymore to choose any values! actually it return undefined in the consoel.

Comment: It's not an error its a warning. You need to pass as an object rather then using {{}} double curly brackets. I updated my answer please give a try

Comment: I got an error:  Unexpected token, expected }    here                                     start: JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('priceSlider')).start,

Comment: Can you do console.log(localStorage.getItem('priceSlider')) and let me know what it prints

Comment: it gives: {"start":20000,"end":50000}

Comment: Can you try defaultSelected = {{
  start: localStorage.getItem('priceSlider').start,
  end: localStorage.getItem('priceSlider').end
}}

Comment: value: {start: NaN, end: NaN}
PriceFilterModal.js:28 value.start: NaN
PriceFilterModal.js:30 localStorageonPrice: Storage {carsbrand: "", carsmodel: "", priceSlider: "{"start":null,"end":null}", length: 3}
PriceFilterModal.js:34 OBJ: {start: null, end: null}
PriceFilterModal.js:35 start: null
PriceFilterModal.js:36 end: null  and   it make an Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: and the console.log(localStorage.getItem('priceSlider'));   gives {"start":null,"end":null}

Comment: @AfefMokhtari I found the issue. Take the latest code from my answer and try from your end

Comment: the working solution generate an error in this ligne const start = JSON.parse(priceSlider).start; which is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: Please check the working demo linked in my answer. Dono why it’s breaking in your machine